# Building complex signals in Mathematica

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

How to build a particular signal in Mathematica such that we have a sine curve for half cycle, then have zeros for some time and this continues?

It is simple to have the zeros for the second half cycle using the function `Max[Sin[t],0]`.

But what if the zeros extend for a time which is strictly not equal to half cycle?

Please show me the method to develop this.

Comment: Perhaps read the documentation for the `PieceWise` function in Mathematica and see if you can use that to do what you want

Comment: Thanks @Bill. Forgot about piecewise functions. I will positively look into it. Meanwhile if you find anything readymade, please do answer.

Comment: `Piecewise` is probably the best option, but just to offer another way: you can multiply by an appropriately shifted and flipped `UnitStep`, e.g. `Sin[t] UnitStep[Pi - t]`. Note that the function `Depress[x0_, x1_] := (UnitStep[x0 - #] + UnitStep[# - x1] &) /; x1 >= x0` will be zero between `x0` and x1` and 1 otherwise, and so multiplying `Sin[t]` by `Depress[x0, x1][t]` will cause zeros in that range.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach :

```
Plot[Sin[2 Pi x] If[SawtoothWave[x] > 2/3 , 0, 1]
   , {x, -2, 2}
   , Exclusions -> None
   , PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]